# Checkbox callback function not getting called from second onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am creating a table dynamically in the run time based on some action in UI as follows

```
     $(figure.children.data).each(function (i, Column) {
            if (i != 0) {
                var callBack = function () {
                    RemoveColumn(figure, Column.figure.id);
                }

                var input = $("<input>")
                            .attr("type", "checkbox")
                            .attr("checked", "checked")
                            .on("change", callBack);

                var tr = $('#tblEntity').append('<tr>');

                $("<td>").appendTo(tr).append(input);

                $("<td>").appendTo(tr).append(Column.figure.text);
            }
 });
```

and the `RemoveColumn` function is as follows.

```
function RemoveColumn(figureToBeModified,columnID) {    
    $(figureToBeModified.children.data).each(function (i, column) {
        if (column.figure.id == columnID) {
            figureToBeModified.hide(column.figure);

            figureToBeModified.remove(column.figure);
        }
    });
}
```

**Problem:** When i un check the check box for the first time it is working fine(means `RemoveColumn` function is getting called),but afterwords if i check or un check the checkbox `RemoveColumn` is not getting called.

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: I agree.  I can't see anything inherently wrong with your change event javascript but without knowing more about what the figure stuff is it is hard to say whats wrong.  With a [very simplified approach](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9vxapj/) it seems to work when it is called again.

Answer (score 0):

The line `var tr = $('#tblEntity').append('<tr>');` will add a tr to the table but it will not assign it to tr.

I think you meant something like this:

```
    var tr = $("<tr>");
    $('#tblEntity').append(tr);    
    $("<td>").appendTo(tr).append(input);
    $("<td>").appendTo(tr).append(Column.figure.text);
```

Also, wouldn't it be easier if RemoveColumn was defined like this:

```
function RemoveColumn(figureToBeModified, column) {
    figureToBeModified.hide(column.figure);    
    figureToBeModified.remove(column.figure);
}
```

and called like this:

```
var callBack = function () {
    RemoveColumn(figure, Column);
}
```

If remove and hide act anything like the jQuery remove and hide then why hide it just to remove it all together on the next line?

None of these directly address your question and I need more info about your figure data to make sense of it but maybe this will help you get closer to where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a scope problem.

The variable `callback` is a function that receives parameters. However, the way it is right now is only taking the last values passed to it.

I advise to change it to this:

```
var callback = function(fig, figId) {
     return function() {
         RemoveColumn(fig, figId);
     }
}
```

Then create the checkbox like this:

```
var input = $("<input>")
            .attr("type", "checkbox")
            .attr("checked", "checked")
            .on("change", callBack(figure, Column.figure.id));
```

That way the `RemoveColumn()` function will always have the correct values for use.

Answer (score 0):

> When i un check the check box for the first time it is working
>   fine(means RemoveColumn function is getting called),but afterwords if
>   i check or un check the checkbox RemoveColumn is not getting called

Try commenting this line:

```
if (column.figure.id == columnID) {
    figureToBeModified.hide(column.figure);
    //figureToBeModified.remove(column.figure);/* on first call it gets removed, so its not available for next time */
}
```